# How to create email/password based account using Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I tried creating an email/password based account using the Firebase Admin SDK, but it is creating an anonymous account. Here's my code for doing this:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
    email: "jdoe@gmail.com",
    emailVerified: false,
    password: "secretPassword",
    displayName: "John Doe",
    disabled: false
});
```

What am I missing? I even tried setting `emailVerified` to true.

P.S. Here's the API documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: That should create an email and password user. What makes you think it is an anonymous user? Did you try signInWithEmailAndPassword with the newly created user?

Comment: Because when I look at it from the Firebase console - it shows an "Anonymous User". Also when I try to get the user by email (admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)) it does not return anything.

Comment: @bojeil, this turned out to be a dumb error on my part which had nothing to do with Firebase. This is a non-issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: I had the same problem on a project, getting anonymous users created instead of real users even though I'm providing email and displayName. Can you share what was your dumb error? (in case I'm making a similar dumb error?)